# How to emulate if-elseif-else in Ant without using Ant-contrib?

Tags: ant, ant-contrib

I need an if-elseif-else conditional statement in Ant.

I do not want to use Ant-contrib.

I tried the solution [here](http://jaysonlorenzen.wordpress.com/2010/03/10/apache-ant-if-else-condition-without-ant-contrib/)

```
    <target name="condition.check">
    <input message="Please enter something: " addproperty="somethingProp"/>
    <condition property="allIsWellBool">
        <not>
            <equals arg1="${somethingProp}" arg2="" trim="true"/>
        </not>
    </condition>
</target>
<target name="if" depends="condition.check, else" if="allIsWellBool">
    <echo message="if condition executes here"/>
</target>
<target name="else" depends="condition.check" unless="allIsWellBool">
    <echo message="else condition executes here"/>
</target>
```

But I will have to set properties inside the if and else targets which will not be visible in the calling target.

Is there any other way out using conditions?

Answer (score 4):

Move the dependencies out of `if` and `else` into a new target that depends on all of the other targets:

```
<project name="ant-if-else" default="newTarget">
    <target name="newTarget" depends="condition.check, if, else"/>

    <target name="condition.check">
        <input message="Please enter something: " addproperty="somethingProp"/>
        <condition property="allIsWellBool">
            <not>
                <equals arg1="${somethingProp}" arg2="" trim="true"/>
            </not>
        </condition>
    </target>

    <target name="if" if="allIsWellBool">
        <echo message="if condition executes here"/>
    </target>
    <target name="else" unless="allIsWellBool">
        <echo message="else condition executes here"/>
    </target>
</project>
```